# enable auto-completion of apt-get for non-privileged user?

Tags: apt, bash, sudo, auto-completion

I've enabled apt-get in SUDO without password , and bash autocompletion for it need to be enabled as well , but how ?

```
If i try to source that file:
%> . /etc/bash_completion.d/apt
No command 'have' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vave' from package 'lipsia' (universe)
 Command 'havp' from package 'havp' (universe)
 Command 'haxe' from package 'haxe' (universe)
 Command 'dave' from package 'libhttp-dav-perl' (universe)
 Command 'save' from package 'atfs' (universe)
have: command not found
No command 'have' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vave' from package 'lipsia' (universe)
 Command 'havp' from package 'havp' (universe)
 Command 'haxe' from package 'haxe' (universe)
 Command 'dave' from package 'libhttp-dav-perl' (universe)
 Command 'save' from package 'atfs' (universe)
have: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `have()` is defined in `/etc/bash_completion`, so it is not possible to execute `/etc/bash_completion.d/apt` in isolation.

I think you would need to run the command

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

and it will then execute all the completion scripts in the `/etc/bash_completion.d` directory.

However, I'm not sure why you would need to do this anyway.  On my systems (natty and oneiric) completion for `apt-get` already works with or without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

From your prompt it seems that you are using `zsh`, is it true?

`bash-completion`, as the name says, is the completion for `bash`, so it is not guaranteed to work for other shells, though partially compatible with `bash`.

Comment: nope , it's bash